# BitTorrent peer_id encoded format, Invalid Request

Tags: java, format, bittorrent

I am trying to format a tracker request using [BitTorrentSpecification](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_HTTP.2FHTTPS_Protocol) but I don't get how to format the plan string peerID I am generating. A sample of both from my program is:

```
New Session ID generated: -MC0001-948902816289 
Session ID URLEncoded: %-M%C0%00%1-%94%89%02%81%62%89
```

Do I send that? I am getting Invalid request from the server... I have tested and my info_hash is valid. Sample request below.

```
http://tracker.tfile.me/announce?info_hash=%B5%E1%3F%36%35%09%62%85%A2%F4%B9%C8%9A%75%E9%F1%CC%BD%C3%CD&peer_id=%-M%C0%00%1-%94%89%02%81%62%89&port=6888&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=4018984971&compact=0
```

Comment: @Encombe thanks, but tracker still is replying invalid request

Comment: @Encombe Thanks! I am now getting a proper response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLencoding of the peer_id is not correctly done and it don't need to be URLencoded, as all the characters in it is URL-safe. Send it as: `...&peer_id=-MC0001-948902816289&...`

Also, `compact=1` is more or less obligatory today. Very few trackers support the legacy non compact reply. Change to `...&compact=1` and it will work.

There is also no `event=started`, it should be there if it's the first time the tracker is contacted.

Send:

```
http://tracker.tfile.me/announce?info_hash=%B5%E1%3F%36%35%09%62%85%A2%F4%B9%C8%9A%75%E9%F1%CC%BD%C3%CD&peer_id=-MC0001-948902816289&port=6888&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=4018984971&event=started&compact=1
```

and the reply is:

```
d8:completei0e10:downloadedi0e10:incompletei1e8:intervali2988e12:min intervali1494e5:peers6:******
```

Comment: Reply was not as said (reply was d14:failure reason3:ERRe), However considering I got no reply before this is marked as the answer.

Comment: The error is probably caused by that we used the same peer_id. It worked for me.

Comment: I tried it in browser as well and changed the ID to peer_id=-MC0001-948209816289... Same error

Comment: Also change to another info_hash and it will work. The error seems to be somewhat persistent for a info_hash,IP-tuple.

Comment: what do you mean different hash? Why doesn't my hash work?

Comment: To end use event=stopped, otherwise may be time based. It seems anyways.

Comment: It will probably time out after something like interval*1.5